# Task scheduler trigger when system boot in C#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have created a task scheduler and set its trigger time fixed e.g. daily-5:00 pm, but I want to trigger that event when system start or boot. Please help me with code if you have any example.

Thanks in Advance.

Code :------------------------------------------------------

```
 public static void CreateTask()
        {
            using (TaskService task = new TaskService())
            {`enter code here`
                TaskDefinition taskdDef = task.NewTask();

                taskdDef.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";
                taskdDef.RegistrationInfo.Documentation = "http://www.mysite.com";

                taskdDef.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                taskdDef.Settings.AllowDemandStart = true;

                taskdDef.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"D:\Myfolder\bin\SGSclient.exe", "yourArguments", null));
                task.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("YourTask", taskdDef);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create a windows task and just start it at system startup using Task Scehduler

Comment: I tried with window service also. let me clear first, I have a window appliation and make a setup of that file. after that i created window service and give the path of that setup file in window service. Problem is here, when i create one more setup for that window service. becuase i want to use like a setup, so that can install at any system.

Comment: There is [this good library](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) to help on Task Scheduling. I don't write this as an answer because I don't know if it can handle the boot requirement

Answer (score 13):

Using the [Task Scheduler Manager Library](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler) from GitHub, you could write this

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Get the service on the local machine
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire after the system boot
         td.Triggers.Add(new BootTrigger() );

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve,  very nice tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the registry as a start task. See [here](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/startup_0401.html).

Comment: Doesn't work while having a program that request admin rights

Answer (score 1):

2000, XP

Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks
Open the properties of the task.
Open the "Schedule" tab.
From the "Schedule Task" pull-down select "At System Startup".

Vista

Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler
Open the properties of the task.
Open the "Triggers" tab, then edit or create a trigger.
From the "begin the task" pulldown select "At Startup".

Comment: That's not help if the client have to do the work by himself ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a [Windows Servic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C)e.

Comment: A service to run an application? Isn't a little bit excessive? Moreover he may (or not, we don't know) to have some UI.

Comment: Is it not possible in task scheduler ?

Comment: Thanks Asif, I tried with window service also. let me clear first, I have a window appliation and make a setup of that file. after that i created window service and give the path of that setup file in window service. Problem is here, when i create one more setup for that window service. becuase i want to use like a setup, so that can install at any system.

Comment: What i got from your comments is that you don't want two installers. I think you can make a single installer of the application and the service.