# TaskScheduler not creating task though command is getting called

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, scheduled-tasks, custom-action

I have a WiX installer in which I have the below custom actions to create a couple of tasks in task scheduler.

```
[CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CreateScheduleTaskForUpdateTriggering(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Creating the Scheduled Task");
            string MyAppPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyAppPATH");
            if (!IsTaskExisting("MyAppUpdateTrigger"))
            {
                session.Log("Command Created : " + "C:\\Windows\\System32\\SCHTASKS.exe /Create /TN \"MyAppUpdateTrigger\" /SC ONCE /TR \"" + Path.Combine(new string[] { MyAppPath, "Watchdog", "RunMyAppInstaller.bat" }) + "\" /RL HIGHEST");
                Process p = Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\SCHTASKS.exe", " /Create /TN \"MyAppUpdateTrigger\" /SC ONCE /TR \"" + Path.Combine(new string[] { MyAppPath, "Watchdog", "RunMyAppInstaller.bat" }) + "\" /ST 00:00:00 /SD 01/01/1990 /RL HIGHEST");
            }
            else
            {
                session.Log("MyAppUpdateTrigger schedule already exists");
            }
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }

        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Creating the Scheduled Task for running watch dog");

            string MyAppPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyAppPATH");

            if (!IsTaskExisting("RunWatchDog"))
            {
                session.Log("Command Created : " + "C:\\Windows\\System32\\SCHTASKS.exe /Create /TN \"RunWatchDog\" /SC ONSTART /TR \"" + Path.Combine(new string[] { MyAppPath, "Watchdog", "RunWatchDog.bat" }) + "\" /RL HIGHEST");
                Process p = Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\SCHTASKS.exe", " /Create /TN \"RunWatchDog\" /SC ONSTART /TR \"" + Path.Combine(new string[] { MyAppPath, "Watchdog", "RunWatchDog.bat" }) + "\" /ST 00:00:00 /SD 01/01/1990 /RL HIGHEST");
            }
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
```

I am calling these as shown below in my WiX file.

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_scheduleTaskAction" BinaryKey="removeFolderCustomActionDLL" DllEntry="CreateScheduleTaskForUpdateTriggering" Execute="commit" Return="ignore" />
<CustomAction Id="CA_scheduleTaskActionForWatchDog" BinaryKey="removeFolderCustomActionDLL" DllEntry="CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog" Execute="commit" Return="ignore" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <!--Custom Action="LaunchWatchdog" After="InstallFinalize" /-->
  <Custom Action="WatchDog.TaskKill" Before="InstallValidate"/>
  <Custom Action="CA_scheduleTaskAction" After="InstallFiles"/>
  <Custom Action="CA_scheduleTaskAction" After="InstallFiles"/>
  <Custom Action="CA_myCustomAction" Before="InstallFinalize">Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Though the 1st scheduled task gets created, second one is missing in the task scheduler. Logs do indicate that the custom action has run. But it doesn't exist in the task scheduler. When I run the command manually, it does get created. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated. Below are the logs.

```
    Calling custom action CustomActionRemoveFolder!CustomActionRemoveFolder.CustomActions.CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog
Creating the Scheduled Task for running watch dog
Command Created : C:\Windows\System32\SCHTASKS.exe /Create /TN "RunWatchDog" /SC ONSTART /TR "C:\Program Files\Kube2.0\Watchdog\RunWatchDog.bat" /RL HIGHEST
MSI (s) (88:38) [09:42:01:431]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (88:38) [09:42:01:431]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (88:38) [09:42:01:431]: Unlocking Server
MSI (s) (88:38) [09:42:01:446]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 9:42:01: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
Action ended 9:42:01: INSTALL. Return value 1.
```

Comment: Have you tried programmatic way which is more reliable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383448(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I printed the error code. This is what I am getting. "-2147467259" Any ideas? :(

Comment: That is a runtime error, Reason may vary. Hard to say.

Comment: Figured the issue. It's with the "startup" command. When I say "once" it works fine. Any idea man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I see. From doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

> **/SC schedule**
>
> A value that specifies the schedule frequency. Valid values are: MINUTE, HOURLY, DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY, ONCE, ONLOGON, ONIDLE, and ONEVENT.

Comment: oh! how can I give this onstart command through command line? Because other methods of task scheduler schedule would need some code change :(

Comment: Also in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438482/set-task-to-run-on-system-startup-schtasks-command-line they say it can be done noh?

Comment: Besides, its working when I manually run this command through commandline!

Comment: Right, the doc is a bit confusing. I am walking thru it now.

Comment: Try this, compare yours to example. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_startup

Comment: right. so I do recommend you to create it thru programmatic code rather than command line. it's more reliable.

Comment: In that too, there are no examples of running it on startup. People have used Quartz to schedule it. :(

Comment: See here for C# version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833015/task-scheduler-trigger-when-system-boot-in-c-sharp